# Trying to accomplish similar functionality of .contains on an array of string using substring

Tags: regex, arrays, vb.net, string-comparison

I have an array of directory paths:

```
Directory.GetFiles(uploadPath)
```

I want to check this array to see if a file exists in one of the file paths. After looking at some of the similar questions on SO, I came up with the below. This would work except it will not match since the file name is a substring of the path in the array. I was trying to avoid a loop.

```
If Array.IndexOf(Directory.GetFiles(uploadPath), fileName) > -1 Then
    'do some cool coding stuff
    Exit Sub
End If
```

My other thought was that the GetFiles method has a searchPattern as string parameter, I am guessing I could put a regex there to return the value after the last '\'.

so now i have this which works perfectly:

```
 If Directory.GetFiles(uploadPath, fileName).Length > 0 Then
     'do some code stuff
      Exit Sub
  End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The searchPattern argument of GetFiles doesn't take a RegEx and it matches only against the filename, so you wouldn't need to do anything really fancy.  Just call GetFiles passing in the directory name to search as the first argument and the filename you are looking for as the second.

Comment: Ah ok, that makese since. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than all that, have you tried the in-built:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName()
```

That should give you just the file name right away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If used that method, I would still have to loop through each path in the array to get the file name for comparison. the directory.getfiles grabs all the file paths from the directory path I provide. So, if I have 50 files, it returns an array of 50 path strings.